# Python create new array for different iteration of a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want to create a new array (or list) for every iteration. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
data2 = open('pathways.dat', 'r', errors = 'ignore')
pathways = data2.readlines()

special_line_indexes = []
PWY_ID = []
line_cont = []
L_PRMR = [] #Left primary

#i is the line number (first element of enumerate), while line is the line content (2nd elem of enumerate)
for CUI in just_compound_id:
    for i,line in enumerate(pathways):
        if '//' in line:
            #fint the indexes of the lines containing //
            special_line_indexes = i+1
        elif 'REACTION-LAYOUT -' in line:
            if CUI in line:
                PWY_ID.append(special_line_indexes)
```

Specifically I want to create a different array PWY_ID for a different iteration of CUI (the first foor loop). What I end up is instead a long array with all the output. Maybe it would be more efficient to use a dictionary, but I am not sure how to implement it in a for loop...

Answer (score 0):

You can start mapping out the data schema you want. Decide what would be key and what would be value.

Then, you can start by creating a dict()

```
foo = dict()
```

And you insert items into dictionary by 

`foo["KEY"] = "VALUE"`

for example, 
`foo["x"] = 12`

then, the value will be stored in the dictionary.

Here is a tutorial about how to use dictionary in python:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j7ox_zqM4g